# Change node/attribute name of a converted dictionary (c#) to XML

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I have used this post to convert my dictionary to xml:

[Easy way to convert a Dictionary<string, string> to xml and visa versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799767/easy-way-to-convert-a-dictionarystring-string-to-xml-and-visa-versa)

What I'm doing:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dicEntityRules = new Dictionary<int, string>();
// add the items to dicEntityRules    

DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(dicEntityRules.GetType());

         using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
         {
             using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
             {                    
                 writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                 serializer.WriteObject(writer, dicEntityRules);

                 writer.Flush();

                 sw.ToString();
             }

         }
```

But, my xml is like that:

```
<KeyValueOfintstring>
    <Key>2048</Key>
    <Value>66</Value>
  </KeyValueOfintstring>
```

Can I change this node/atribute names?

I would like some like this:

```
     <Order>
        <entity>2048</entity>
        <rule>66</rule>
      </Order>
```

Regards.

murphy
[[|]]'s

Comment: also please post your code for conversion

Comment: posted Habib. Is this what are you asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your dictionary to a `List<Order>` and serialize that:

```
void Main()
{
    var dicEntityRules = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    dicEntityRules.Add(1, "One");

    // Convert to List<Order>
    var orders = dicEntityRules.Select (er => 
        new Order {entity=er.Key, rule=er.Value}).ToList();

    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Order>));

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {                    
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            serializer.WriteObject(writer, orders);

            writer.Flush();

            var s = sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}

[DataContract()]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember]
    public int entity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string rule { get; set; }
}
```