# Serialize Dictionary(string, List<string>) into xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to convert a Dictionary<string, string> to xml and visa versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799767/easy-way-to-convert-a-dictionarystring-string-to-xml-and-visa-versa)

I have sample class:

```
public class SampleClass
{
   public Dictionary<string, List<string>> SampleProperties {get;set;}
}
```

I want serialize this class to xml.
How I can do this?
I want output xml similar to this example:

```
<DataItem>
   <key>
      <value></value>
      <value></value>
      <value></value>
   </key>
</DataItem>
```

Regards

Comment: The key of your dictionary is a string. Where do you want it to appear in the resulting XML? Could you provide an example data and example expected XML?

Comment: <DataItem><Name><value>Greg</value><value>Tom</value></Name><City><value>London</value><value>Warsaw</value></City><DataItem>. I want to save Name or City as key, and value as List<string>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Linq to Xml to create required xml from your SampleClass object:

```
SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();
sample.SampleProperties = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
    { "Name", new List<string>() { "Greg", "Tom" } },
    { "City", new List<string>() { "London", "Warsaw" } }
};

var result = new XElement("DataItem", 
                 sample.SampleProperties.Select(kvp =>
                    new XElement(kvp.Key, 
                      kvp.Value.Select(value => new XElement("value", value)))));
result.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Output:

```xml
<DataItem>
   <Name>
      <value>Greg</value>
      <value>Tom</value>
   </Name>
   <City>
      <value>London</value>
      <value>Warsaw</value>
   </City>
</DataItem>
```

---

De-serializing from xml:

```xml
SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();
sample.SampleProperties = XElement.Load(path_to_xml).Elements().ToDictionary(
                              e => e.Name.LocalName,
                              e => e.Elements().Select(v => (string)v).ToList());
```

Comment: It's work ;) Could you help me in serialize from xml to this class?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code snippet

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dict.Add("a1", new List<string>(){"a1","a2","a3"});

XElement root = new XElement("DataItem");

foreach(var item in dict)
{
  XElement element = new XElement("Key",item.Key);
  item.Value.ForEach (x => element.Add (new XElement("Value",x)));
  root.Add(element);
}
```