# Populate a dictionary<string, List<string>> from XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to populate a dictionary of type `<string, List<string>>` with the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Currencies>
  <Currency name="USD">
    <symbol>$</symbol>
    <symbol>USD</symbol>
    <symbol>Dollar</symbol>
  </Currency>
  <Currency name="INR">
    <symbol>Rs.</symbol>
    <symbol>₹</symbol>
  </Currency>
```

in a dictionary

```
Dictionary dctCurrency<string,List<string>>;
```

in this the currency name should be the key and all the symbol elements should be in the list of string.

TIA

I have tried the following code,

```
var currencyXmlDocument = XDocument.Load(currencySymbolsDefinition);
var currencies = currencyXmlDocument.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>();
currencySymbolsConfiguration = currencies.ToDictionary(l => l.Attribute("name").Value
    , l => l.Attribute("code").Value);
```

but it isnt compiling

Comment: that's great - but what have you tried?

Comment: very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799767/easy-way-to-convert-a-dictionarystring-string-to-xml-and-visa-versa?rq=1

Comment: If it's not compiling, it *probably* tells you why. - Also, where does the attribute `"code"` come from all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dctCurrency;
dctCurrency = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("Currency")
               select new
               {
                  Key = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                  Value = c.Elements("symbol").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
               }).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

or using extension methods:

```
dctCurrency = doc.Root.Descendants("Currency")
                      .Select(c => new
                      {
                         Key = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                         Value = c.Elements("symbol").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
                      })
                      .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It's error prone with no checks but can give you a basic idea.

```
var str = @"<Currencies>
  <Currency name='USD'>
    <symbol>$</symbol>
    <symbol>USD</symbol>
    <symbol>Dollar</symbol>
  </Currency>
  <Currency name='INR'>
    <symbol>Rs.</symbol>
    <symbol>₹</symbol>
  </Currency>
</Currencies>";
 var xx = XElement.Parse(str);

 var result = xx.Descendants("Currency")
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value, 
        x=>x.Descendants("symbol").Select(xy=>xy.Value).ToList());
```

Comment: I wasnt able to populate the list using 'x=>x.Descendants("symbol").Select(xy=>xy.Value).ToList())' fixed it

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have an xml as below:

```
<root>
      <key>value</key>
</root>
```

The Element to Dictionary will be as follows:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse("<root><key>value</key></root>");
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var el in rootElement.Elements())
{
   dict.Add(el.Name.LocalName, el.Value);
}
```

I don't know if that helps.